# wiki xml dump function

Tags: python, xml, wiki

Looking to create a function that goes through the xml file article and then,

for each article:

if it contains the keywords, *moral* or *ethic*:

move it to another folder, for further processing (into

else:

ignore

I have tried a few things and had a look round but really struggling (not even sure if you can do wildcard searching) as I have only just started using Python, any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Please provide a short representative example of the xml article.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60073966/enwiki-dump-python-function 

Hi Jack, thanks for responding, above is a better formulated question. Thank you :)